# Python dataframe exploded list column into multiple rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
         desc     id     info  
       [a,b,c]     2     type
       [u,v,w]     18    tail
```

Three columns: desc,id,info and desc is a list.I want this:

```
        des    id    info 
         a      2     type
         b      2     type
         c      2     type 
         u      18    tail
         v      18    tail
         w      18    tail
```

That means exploded the list column into multiple rows and other column no changes.
I really don't know how to do this...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one way

```
df.set_index(['id', 'info']).desc.apply(pd.Series).stack()\
.reset_index(name = 'desc').drop('level_2', axis = 1)


    id  info    desc
0   2   type    a
1   2   type    b
2   2   type    c
3   18  tail    u
4   18  tail    v
5   18  tail    w
```

Comment: It works. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

I remenber this should be from piRSquared or cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, but can not find the link ...

```
idx = np.arange(len(df)).repeat(df.desc.str.len(), 0)
out = df.iloc[idx, ].assign(desc=np.concatenate(df.desc.values))
out
Out[100]: 
  desc  id  info
0    a   2  type
0    b   2  type
0    c   2  type
1    u  18  tail
1    v  18  tail
1    w  18  tail
```

Answer (score 2):

You can flatten the `desc` column, `repeat` the other two columns and then concatenate them:

```
pd.concat([
    pd.Series([e for s in df.desc for e in s], name='desc'),
    df.drop('desc', 1).apply(lambda col: col.repeat(df.desc.str.len())).reset_index(drop=True)
], axis=1)

#desc   id  info
#0  a    2  type
#1  b    2  type
#2  c    2  type
#3  u   18  tail
#4  v   18  tail
#5  w   18  tail
```

Answer (score 2):

You could

```
In [1631]: (df.loc[df.index.repeat(df.desc.str.len())]
              .assign(desc=[v for x in df.desc.values for v in x]))
Out[1631]:
  desc  id  info
0    a   2  type
0    b   2  type
0    c   2  type
1    u  18  tail
1    v  18  tail
1    w  18  tail
```